# Copy cells of a column from a sheet to another sheet using nested if statements in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I want to write a code in VBA which dose the following:

1. In Worksheet "Calculation_Results" take every cell from column B BUT not B1
2. If it is equal to `Worksheets("Parameters").Range("A3").Value` then put the value of `Worksheets("SQLresults").Range("A").Value` in `Worksheets("Calculation_Results").Range("A").Cells`
3. If is equal to `Worksheets("Parameters").Range("A4").Value` then
   put the value of  `0.03* Worksheets("SQLresults").Range("B3").Value` in `Worksheets("Calculation_Results").Range("A").Cells`
4. Else `Worksheets("Calculation_Results").Range("A").Cells = 0.03 * Worksheets("SQLresults").Range("B3").Value`

Ok I wrote the following but it dose not work

```
' calculate in Excel the shock
 With ThisWorkbook
   If Len(Sheets("Calculation_Results").name) = 0 Then Else Sheets("Calculation_Results").Delete
     Dim wss As Worksheet
     ' With ThisWorkbook
        Set wss = .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets("SQLresults"))
         wss.name = "Calculation_Results"
         '
' local_calculation Macro
'

'
' With Sheets("Calculation_Results")
     For Each element In Worksheets("SQLresults").Range("B")
       If element.Value = Worksheets("Parameters").Range("A3").Value _
       Then Worksheets("Calculation_Results").Range("A").Cells = Worksheets("SQLresults").Range("A").Value_
              End If
              Else If element.Value = Worksheets("Parameters").Range("A4").Value_
              Then Worksheets("Calculation_Results").Range("A").Cells = 0.03* Worksheets("SQLresults").Range("B3").Value
              End If
              Else
              Worksheets("Calculation_Results").Range("A").Cells = 0.25 * Worksheets("SQLresults").Range("B3").Value
     Next
      End With
```

sorry probably it is easy but I am rather new in VBA! The first part, to create a new  sheet, works well just the second part not :( and I am not able to understand the error message.

Comment: do you really want every cell? or just the rows in the column with `Data`?

Comment: @ScottHoltzman, oh you are right all cells with a value or data. go through `Worksheets("SQLresults").Range("B")` till a free cell

Comment: That is what I thought. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Qualifty all your sheets to variables to make it easier to read and work with
2. Define the last used row in the SQL sheet so you know how many actual rows to check (`Range("B")` is invalid syntax in VBA, you need to define a column and row ... However `Columns("B")` or `Columns(2)` is valid syntax).
3. Loop through each row and evaluate with you criteria to determine what value each corresponding row in the calculation results should be.
4. The use of `Select Case` may be more easier to understand in this example, instead of `If Then Else`.

See this code:

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim wCalc As Worksheet
Dim wSQL As Worksheet
Dim wP As Worksheet

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set wSQL = wb.Sheets("SQLResults")
Set wP = wb.Sheets("Parameters")

With wb

    If Len(.Sheets("Calculation_Results").Name) = 0 Then Else .Sheets("Calculation_Results").Delete

    Set wCalc = .Sheets.Add(After:=wSQL)
    wCalc.Name = "Calculation_Results"

    ' local_calculation Macro
End With

With wSQL

    Dim ERow As Long
    ERow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim element As Range

    For Each element In .Range("B2:B" & ERow)

        Select Case element.Value2

            Case Is = wP.Range("A3").Value2: wCalc.Cells(element.Row, 1) = element.Value2
            Case Is = wP.Range("A4").Value2: wCalc.Cells(element.Row, 1) = element.Value2 * 0.03
            Case Else: wsCalc.Cells(element.Row, 1) = element.Value2 * 0.25

        End Select

      Next

End With
```

As an alternative, you can get rid of the loop altogether and just apply a formula.

Replace this in my code above after resetting the "Calculation_Result" sheet. This Is **untested** and may need a few tweaks.

```
With wSQL

    Dim ERow As Long
    ERow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

End With

With wCalc

    With .Range("A2")
        .Formula = "=IF(SQLResults!B2=Parameters!$A$3,SQLResults!B2,IF(SQLResults!B2=Parameters!$A$4,SQLResults!B2*.03,SQLResults!B2*.25))"
        .Copy

        With .Resize(ERow, 1)
            .PasteSpecial
            .Copy
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End With

    End With

End With
```

Comment: Ì deleted my part and applied your solution I had to redefine ` Dim ERow As Long
    ERow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    ' Dim element As Range

    For Each element In .Range("B2:B" & ERow)
`  but I get another error ` ERow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` with : object required

Comment: did you use it inside a `With` statement working with the SQL sheet` (as I have done)?

Comment: apologies @maniA - please see my edited code. I Dim `wSQL` then used `With wsSQL`. I cleaned everything up to match! Sorry. Good reason to always use `Option Explicit` at the top of each module, to ensure all variables are written correctly!

Comment: Now it is fine I do not have any error more but it is doing something else copied just 2 values in `SQLresults` table in A2 and A3

Comment: what is value of `ERow`?

Comment: Dear Scott I have the solution but I am still interested in yours I show you  my answer and please give your answer based on it.

Comment: @maniA you are still looping through **every** cell in column B with this `& Rows.Count`. What did `ERow` not working? What is it evaluating to when it first gets set?

Comment: @ Scott Holtzman, you are right I have just before recognized it thanks alot grate hint! I changed it a little bit and edit the answer! Thanks  a lot again

Comment: @maniA - seems that you have you're answer. You had a lot of people help you with this, please credit them with upvotes or marking one as an answer, unless you feel you want to mark your own answer as the answer.

Comment: I did it for all :) can I do it 2 times, 2 upvotes? no I can just one time :( . Should I tick yours as answer?

Comment: @maniA - mark whichever answer you feel helped you most or your own, if you prefer :)

Comment: I did yours but that was not a bad question,  right ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your script is very messy.

Try use this following, which I have just tried to neaten up your script.

```
' calculate in Excel the shock
With ThisWorkbook
    If Len(Sheets("Calculation_Results").Name) = 0 Then Else: Sheets("Calculation_Results").Delete

    Dim wss As Worksheet

    ' With ThisWorkbook
    Set wss = .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets("SQLresults"))
    wss.Name = "Calculation_Results"
    '
    ' local_calculation Macro
    '

    '
    '

    With Sheets("Calculation_Results")
    For Each element In Worksheets("SQLresults").Range("B")

        If element.Value = Worksheets("Parameters").Range("A3").Value Then

            Worksheets("Calculation_Results").Range("A").Cells = Worksheets("SQLresults").Range("A").Value

        ElseIf element.Value = Worksheets("Parameters").Range("A4").Value Then

            Worksheets("Calculation_Results").Range("A").Cells = 0.03 * Worksheets("SQLresults").Range("B3").Value

        Else

            Worksheets("Calculation_Results").Range("A").Cells = 0.25 * Worksheets("SQLresults").Range("B3").Value

        End If
    Next
    End With 
End With
```

Comment: Jean-Pierre, thanks but I get the same error as before:  Run-time error '1004' Application-defined or object-defined error. If I go to Debug  ` For Each element In Worksheets("SQLresults").Range("B")`  is highlighted.

Comment: Check  now there was a end with missing and a ' where there should not have been on

Comment: Unfortunately exact the same error :( my problem with vba is I can not understand what error messages say in general

Comment: I defined `element` as follows `Dim element` it should be every cell

Comment: thanks  Jean-Pierre Oosthuizen that was very helpful

Answer (score 1):

```
For Each element In Worksheets("SQLresults").Range("B")
```

Range("B") is undefined

Use Range("B2:B" & rows.count) To go through your specified criteria

Answer (score 0):

```
' calculate in Excel the shock
With ThisWorkbook
    If Len(Sheets("Calculation_Results").name) = 0 Then Else: Sheets("Calculation_Results").Delete

    Dim wss As Worksheet

    ' With ThisWorkbook
    Set wss = .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets("SQLresults"))
    wss.name = "Calculation_Results"
    '
    ' local_calculation Macro
    '

    '
    '

    i = 2
    With Sheets("Calculation_Results")

   Dim ERow As Long
ERow = Worksheets("SQLresults").Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For Each element In .Range("B2:B" & ERow)
        If element.Value = Worksheets("Parameters").Range("A3").Value Then
            Worksheets("Calculation_Results").Range("A" & i) = Worksheets("SQLresults").Range("A" & i).Value
        ElseIf element.Value = Worksheets("Parameters").Range("A4").Value Then
            Worksheets("Calculation_Results").Range("A" & i) = 0.03 * Worksheets("SQLresults").Range("A" & i).Value
        Else
            Worksheets("Calculation_Results").Range("A" & i) = 0.25 * Worksheets("SQLresults").Range("A" & i).Value
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Next
    End With
End With
```